# CPT Validation to not show "Post updated."

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, save-post, notices

Now this has been asked several times over on all WP forums, but how you change the success message?

First, I know there are 2 choices for managing the error message: setting in the options and using a session.  I chose the latter.  With concurrent users, the setting of error messages in the options just sounds like a bad idea.  Personally, I wish I did not have to do either, but WP is stateless, so I don't have a choice.

So, this is my basic code.

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function my_admin_notices(){
  if(!empty($_SESSION['my_admin_notices'])) print $_SESSION['my_admin_notices'];
  unset ($_SESSION['my_admin_notices']);
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notices' );

Plugin::initialize(); // do all the wonderful plugin stuff

// at the very end, remove the notices from the session
if(isset($_SESSION['my_admin_notices']))
  $value = '';
```

Also, I added this to my Plugin class when doing the `add_action('save_post', $callback_function)`.

```
$_SESSION['my_admin_notices'] .= '<div class="error"><p>Something bad happened!</p></div>';
```

Everything works when I click "Update" on my post.  I get a nice error message of "Something bad happened!", but I have a problem.

I also see "Post updated."

Not good.

I skipped all the logic on updating and even did a "`return false;`", but the callback_function evidently does not process a boolean return and probably any return value for that matter.

How do I fix this so there is NO "Post updated." message?

If there is not an easy way with my approach, then what's a better way of doing this?